# How to add image on azure easytable

Tags: azure, xamarin, xamarin.forms, azure-mobile-services

I created app with xamarin.forms and I would like to send a picture to azure, but in easytable not exist type blolb only string,number, bool and date.

It's possible send a img to easytable ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should really upload blobs to [Blob storage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/storage-xamarin-blob-storage) instead.

```csharp
using (var fileStream = System.IO.File.OpenRead(@"path\img.jpg"))
{
    await blockBlob.UploadFromStreamAsync(fileStream);
}
```

or

```csharp
byte[] imageBytes;
// read your image into imageBytes
await blockBlob.UploadByteArrayAsync(imageBytes);
```

Table storage has an [`Edm.Binary` property type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/understanding-the-table-service-data-model). Properties are limited to 64KB in size.

If the SDK does not expose the type, convert to base64 and store as `string`. Again, that's highly undesirable for performance and efficiency. You are left with roughly 48KB of storage for a single image (base64 is ~1.33 times the source size as it encodes each 3 bytes into 4).